# Getting an id after mass asignment

Tags: laravel

Ok so we can create a new user:

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = 'Megauser'
$user->save();
```

And then we can add some user items:

```
$item = new Item;
$item->user_id = $user->id; //id we got from a freshly created user
$item->quantity = '9000';
$item->save();
```

But what if we mass assign the user?

```
User::create([
    'name' => 'Megauser'
)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The create method will return the new object with its ID.

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => 'Megauser'
)];

$userId = $user->id
```

Or as Rob Gordijn pointed out below, if you are worried about key names, you can use the `getKey()` call.

```
$userId = $user->getKey();
```

This is necessary if someone overrides the column name in their Eloquent model. For example:

```
class Example extends Eloquent {
    $primaryKey = 'uid';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => 'Megauser'
)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for

```
<?php
$User = User::create([
    'name' => 'Huzzah'
)];
$UserKey = $User->getKey();
```

to ensure your still works when someone decides to changes the column name ;)